# Does there exist a midsquare with natural sides and diagonal?

Tags: geometry, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic-geometry

A **midsquare** is an orthodiagonal and equidiagonal quadrilateral.

[image: midsquare]

Are there **naturals** $a,b,c,d,e$ such that the quadrilateral with sides $a,b,c,d$ and diagonal $e$ is a midsquare ?

$e^2$ is a solution for $$2e^4-2(a^2+c^2)e^2+(a^2-b^2)^2+(b^2-c^2)^2=0$$
Let $D=4b^2d^2-(a^2-c^2)^2$
Then $e^2=\dfrac{a^2+c^2+\sqrt{D}}2$

```
p=1 
q=5000
import math
for a in range (p,q): # a = AB 
    for b in range(a,q): # b = BC
        for c in range (p,q): # c = CD
            if a*a+c*c > b*b:
               d = (a*a+c*c-b*b)**.5 # d = DA
               if int(d)==d:
                  d=int(d)
                  D = 4*b*b*d*d-(a*a-c*c)*(a*a-c*c) 
                  if D>=0:
                     if int(D**.5)==D**.5:
                        e = (.5*(a*a+c*c+D**.5))**.5
                        if int(e)==e: 
                           print(a+b+c+d+e+e,a,b,c,d,e,e)
```

Some results with $\sqrt{D}\in\mathbb{N}$
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\text{perimeter-plus } a+b+c+d+2e & \sqrt{D} & e^2&e\\
\hline
658.488\approx35+101+149+115+2\times 129.244& 9982 & 16704&24\sqrt{29}\\
\hline
1183.63\approx41+181+289+229+2\times 221.815& 13202 &  49202& \sqrt{2\times73\times337}\\
\hline
3738.168\approx221+481+899+791+2\times673.084& 49042 &  453042& 3\sqrt{2\times25169}\\
\hline
6105.496\approx299+925+1405+1099+2\times1188.748&762818 & 1413122& \sqrt{2\times706561}\\
\hline
7611.367\approx85+1339+1939+1405+2\times1421.684&275422& 2021184& 264\sqrt{29}\\
\hline
11665.227\approx845+1513+2525+2191+2\times2295.614& 3450034 & 5269842& 3\sqrt{2\times137\times2137}\\
\hline
11992.528\approx1015+1241+2759+2665+2\times2156.264& 656642 & 4649474& \sqrt{2\times661\times3517}\\
\hline
17069.827\approx709+2759+3995+2975+2\times3315.913 &5527858& 10995282 & 3\sqrt{2\times610849}\\
\hline
21602.357\approx1681+2381+4889+4589+2\times4031.178&5772718 &16250400& 60\sqrt{2\times37\times61}\\
\hline
37947.648\approx1321+6329+9049+6601+2\times 7323.824 &23647358 & 53638400&1360\sqrt{29}\\
\hline
44392.996\approx2509+7081+9901+7361+2\times8770.498&49518382&76921632&12\sqrt{2\times89\times3001}\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Two special cases

1. The **isosceles trapezoid midsquare** $a,b,c,b,e,e$.
   It's easy to show that with $a,b,c,e$ integers, it doesn't exist: a nice geometric expression for $e$ as a function of $a$ and $c$.
2. The **kite midsquare** $a,a,c,c,e,e,~a<c$.
   I don't know whether it exists or not.
   For it, I can't even find an **integer** $\sqrt{D}=\sqrt{4a^2c^2-(a^2-c^2)^2}$.
   20/11/23 Let $g$ be the distance between the midpoints of the diagonals (see Euler's quadrilateral theorem), we can show that $$a^2+2eg=c^2$$ So $g$ is a rational number, we can look for $e$ and $g$ naturals such that $$(e-g)^2+g^2=2a^2$$ $$(e+g)^2+g^2=2c^2$$
   Example of an "almost solution" $$(1192-1043)^2+1043^2=1~110~050=2\times745^2~~~~~~~~~~$$ $$(1192+1043)^2+1043^2=6~083~074=2\times1744^2~\boxed{+2}$$
   I still don't find any solution.

Comment: What is a pseudo-square? $\quad$ How would you attempt to prove this statement?

Comment: I wrote some python programs and didn't find any natural midsquare.

Comment: Can you post these into the statement itself, not just as comments. MSE asks the poster to show their work to prevent closing of the statement, so this would be helpful.

Comment: Let O be the intersection of the diagonals. We could name $x=OA=\dfrac{a^2-b^2+e^2}{2e}$, $y=OB$, $z=OC$, $t=OD$, yes they would be rational, if $ABCD$ integer exists.